# Is it possible to use the same SSL certificate for http and ftp?

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, domain-name, ftps

Using https://example.com, I wonder if it is possible to use its SSL certificate for ftps://example.com ? The used certificate is basic like (RapidSSL, PositiveSSL, etc ...)

Comment: If you want a more specific answer, you're going to need to post some additional details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, why shouldn't it?
A server certificate identifies a host (by DNS name or IP), not a service. All services on a host can (IMHO even should) use the same certificate.

Comment: So, it is possible to use http, ftp, on the same static IP since the domain name is the same ?

Comment: Yes. A client will basically compare the server's name (the one it connects to) with the subject of the certificate -- if they match the cert is accepted. [ignoring wildcards, CAs, etc. for now]  So in theory a DNS based certificate will even work with a dynamic IP, as long as the client's name resolution is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can without any issues.